# How to display a value on Tkinter window from a function every second?

Tags: python, tkinter, time, python-multithreading

So I'm working on a function does something (turns a motor) every second. For counting the second I use time.sleep(1) because I don't know any other way to wait.

```
def wash_loop(wash_time):
    
    count = 0
    dist = 0
    global error_flag
    error_flag = 0
    
    while (count < wash_time):
        if(count%2==0):#going forward
            GPIO.output(Motor_IN1,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Motor_IN2,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Motor_EN,GPIO.HIGH)
            print(count)
            time.sleep(MOTOR_SLEEP)
        
        else:#going backwards
            GPIO.output(Motor_IN1,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Motor_IN2,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Motor_EN,GPIO.HIGH)
            print(wash_time - count) #want to display this on a Tkinter window instead
            time.sleep(MOTOR_SLEEP)

        count+=1
        dist = distance_check()
        if(dist < CRITICAL_DIS):
           error_alert()
           break
        
        if(count>=wash_time):
            GPIO.output(Motor_EN, GPIO.LOW)
            break
```

The Tkinter function that I'm trying to do this in looks like this:

```
def wash_window():
    
    #create the main window for GUI control applcation
        window2 = TK.Tk()
        temp = TK.IntVar()
        
        window2.geometry(WINDOW_GEOMETRY)
        window2.title("Wash Cycle ")
        
        #create the frame that will hold instructions
        frame0 = TK.Frame(window2)
        frame0.pack(side=TK.TOP)
        
        TK.Label(frame0, text="You've selected custom wash cycle").grid(row=0,column=0)
        TK.Label(frame0, text="Please select the water temperature for the wash.")\
                .grid(row=1,column=0)
        
        frame1 = TK.Frame(window2)
        frame1.pack(side=TK.TOP)
        
        temp.get()
        hot_button = TK.Radiobutton(frame1, text="HOT", variable=temp, value=1 ).grid(row=0, column=0)
        cold_button = TK.Radiobutton(frame1, text="COLD", variable=temp, value=2).grid(row=0,column=1)
        warm_button = TK.Radiobutton(frame1, text="WARM", variable=temp, value=3).grid(row=0,column=2)
        
        #create the frame that will hold control entry in the window
        frame2 = TK.Frame(window2)
        frame2.pack(side=TK.TOP)
        TK.Label(frame2, text = "Please enter the time below for the wash cycle").grid(row=0,column=0)
        user_entry = TK.Entry(frame2)
        user_entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
        
        frame3= TK.Frame(window2)
        frame3.pack(side=TK.TOP)
        
           
        start_button = TK.Button(frame3, text="START", command = lambda: wash_cycle(user_entry,temp)).grid(row=0, column=0)
       # stop_button = TK.Button(frame3, text="STOP", command = lambda: wash_cycle(user_entry,temp)).grid(row=0, column=1)
        quit_button = TK.Button(frame3, text="QUIT", command = window2.destroy).grid(row=0, column=2)
```

[image: When I press start, the first function starts executing and then starts the countdown based on the value entered in the box]

What I'm trying to do is display the countdown (from the entered time to 0) on this Tkinter window as soon as the person presses start in the window. This is different from using the `after()` function because I want to show a value from a function which is only executing once, only with the exception that it has a loop.
Thank You!

Comment: We get questions about executing code based on a timer quite often here. Please do some research on the `after` method.

Comment: You can run `wash_loop()` in a thread and update a tkinter `StringVar` linked to a tkinter `Label` widget inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do is work with threading.

You Need to:

from threading Import Timer

Then you create a timer

```
your_timer = Timer(the_seconds_you_want_to_wait, the_function_to_call)
```

You are calling a function with this and in that function you can display anything in your tkinter window.
What I recommend you to do here is create a Label and then change the properties of it.
For example if you want to show a number on a label:

```
L1 = Label(root, text="your text here")
L1.pack()
```

Now if you want to edit that later:

```
L1.configure(text="your new text here")

your_timer.start()
```

And at the end of your function you Need to Start the timer in order to the create a cycle or just create a Loop for it.

Comment: And how do I display that in my Tkinter window?

Comment: If you want to Display a Label on the Screen, you just need to add  the widget to the Label: l1 = Label(window2, …)